# Как програмно сменить фон рабочего стола средствами basic?

Tags: windows, visual-basic, vba, desktop

Как можно програмно сменить фон рабочего стола в Windows средствами basic?

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Влезать в пользовательские настройки, особенно не связанные с Вашим приложением, вообще-то нехорошо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вызов SystemParametersInfo API можно использовать для получения и задания параметров Windows, которые обычно устанавливаются вручную с рабочего стола с помощью панели управления.

[Описание SystemParametersInfo API](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/97142)

Объявляем функцию для смены обоев:

```
Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Integer, ByVal uParam As Integer, ByVal lpvParam As String, ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As Integer
```

Объявляем константы:

```
Private Const SETDESKWALLPAPER = &H14
Private Const UPDATEINIFILE = &H1
```

Вызываем функцию с нужными параметрами:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "ПутьКФайлуИзображения", UPDATEINIFILE)
```

[ссылка на англоязычный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278234/change-desktop-background-using-vb-net)